# Proto 3: A way to add metadata at field level

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto, protobuf-java, proto3

I am using protobuf-gradle-plugin to generate java class from the proto files.

My proto file looks like

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.address;
option java_package = "com.address";


message AddressesMessage {
 int32 id = 1;
 string address_line_1 = 4;
 string address_line_2 = 5;
 string city = 7;
 string postal_code = 9;
 string country = 10;
}
```

The plugin is generating classes for me but now I want to add some metadata information at field level. Like

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.address;
option java_package = "com.address";


message AddressesMessage {
 int32 id = 1 [ (meta) = { isfact: false }];
 string address_line_1 = 4;
 string address_line_2 = 5;
 string city = 7;
 string postal_code = 9;
 string country = 10;
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible via [custom options](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#customoptions), but: you'd need to *define* your custom options in a separate proto2 schema, which the proto3 schema then imports.

Something like (for your proto2 schema, untested):

```proto
syntax = "proto2";
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";
package MetaPackage;
message MyMeta {
  optional bool isFact = 1;
}
extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  optional MyMeta meta = 80412; // numbering: search for "One last thing" in the link above
}
```

then just add:

```proto
import "MyMeta.proto";
```

to your proto3 schema, and it *should* work. Accessing the metadata is another topic, though! See the link above.

Comment: Thanks @Marc Gravell . I followed the instructions and but I am getting an "Unresolved reference" error.

Comment: @jdev where? Which file/line etc? Is that the entire message?

Comment: Is it possible to define a Map as a custom option? Have asked the same on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60982469/in-a-proto-how-can-i-define-a-map-as-a-custom-option

Comment: @JDev I do not believe so